# Chart.js Custom parsing with floating bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I have a floating bar chart that somewhat represents a Gantt chart:

[image]

The dataset looks as follows:

```json
{
    "labels": [
        "Uwe Austermühle",
        "Helmar Conradi",
        "Gero Dippel"
    ],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "data": [
                [
                    "2023-01-05T17:00:00.000Z",
                    "2023-01-08T17:00:00.000Z"
                ],
                [
                    "2022-12-01T12:34:00.000Z",
                    "2023-02-28T12:34:00.000Z"
                ],
                [
                    "2023-01-24T12:39:16.202Z",
                    "2023-02-23T12:39:00.000Z"
                ]
            ],
            "barPercentage": 0.5,
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.8)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a simplified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdcxubsa/).

Problems arise when I try to extend my dataset model by an additional property. Let's say, I want to store some string for each "bar", so that the current model `[Date, Date]` becomes something like this:

```
{
  range: [Date, Date],
  text: string,
}
```

Which would mean, my Dataset would look like that:

```json
{
    "labels": [
        "Uwe Austermühle",
        "Helmar Conradi",
        "Gero Dippel"
    ],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "range": [
                        "2023-01-05T17:00:00.000Z",
                        "2023-01-08T17:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "annotation": "someText"
                },
                {
                    "range": [
                        "2022-12-01T12:34:00.000Z",
                        "2023-02-28T12:34:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "annotation": "someText"
                },
                {
                    "range": [
                        "2023-01-24T12:39:16.202Z",
                        "2023-02-23T12:39:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "annotation": "someText"
                }
            ],
            "barPercentage": 0.5,
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.8)",
            "parsing": {
                "yAxisKey": "range"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this gives me a completly empty chart, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x6zybkvr/).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could change "yAxisKey" to "xAxisKey" because it's horizontal bar (indexAxis: "y").

Furthermore you could add the "y" value to your data with the label instead to use labels (see chartjs doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#parsing).

Dataset:

```
      datasets: [
          {
              data: [
                  {
                      y: "Uwe Austermühle",
                      range: [1,2],
                      annotation: 'test'
                  },
                  {
                      y: "Helmar Conradi",
                      range: [5,6],
                      annotation: 'test'
                  },
                  {
                      y: "Gero Dippel",
                      range: [7,8],
                      annotation: 'test'
                  },
              ],
              barPercentage: 0.5,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.8)",
              parsing: {
                xAxisKey: 'range'
              }
          }
      ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Apparently, one has to specify both `yAxisKey` and `xAxisKey` when using custom parsing.

Answer (score 1):

@user2057925's answer is perfectly right, as well as @Hafnernuss
comment, and unless there's a deep reason behind this (which
I fail to imagine - please let me know) it qualifies as a bug: labels in bar chart are ignored if data is specified through an object.

I certainly don't recommend the following as a feasible solution to
the case in question, but since it may be helpful in the future to
address this issue, I'd mention that it can
be solved (patched) in the source code,
if [`BarController#parseObjectData`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/51441272a781ba575149b214933f0c5b4bafb6ab/src/controllers/controller.bar.js#L324)
does the same as the `BarController#parseArrayAndPrimitive` -
[here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/51441272a781ba575149b214933f0c5b4bafb6ab/src/controllers/controller.bar.js#L164),
that is, add an `|| iScale.parse(labels[i], i)` so it uses the
labels if the `yAxisKey` (or `xAxisKey`) way fails. So the
patched `BarController#parseObjectData` could look like:

```ts
    parseObjectData(meta, data, start, count) {
        const {iScale, vScale} = meta;
        const {xAxisKey = 'x', yAxisKey = 'y'} = this._parsing;
        const iAxisKey = iScale.axis === 'x' ? xAxisKey : yAxisKey;
        const vAxisKey = vScale.axis === 'x' ? xAxisKey : yAxisKey;
        const parsed = [];
        const labels = iScale.getLabels();
        let i, ilen, item, obj;
        for (i = start, ilen = start + count; i < ilen; ++i) {
            obj = data[i];
            item = {};
            item[iScale.axis] = iScale.parse(resolveObjectKey(obj, iAxisKey) || labels[i], i);
            parsed.push(parseValue(resolveObjectKey(obj, vAxisKey), item, vScale, i));
        }
        return parsed;
   }
```

Again, not as practical solution, but as a proof of concept,
here's a [replit](https://replit.com/@kikon/charts-js-BarController-patched)
with it working as @Hafnernuss rightfully
[expected it](https://replit.com/@kikon/charts-js-BarController-patched#index.html) to.